# prettytable python 3.6 ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x, модули

```
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm
from prettytable import PrettyTable
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def fetch_page(url, params=None):
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) '
                      'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                      'Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept-Language': 'ru,en;q=0.9'
    }
    return requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)


def parse_afisha_list(raw_html):
    films_information = {}
    min_showing_cinemas_count = 50
    soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
    tags = soup.find_all(class_='m-disp-table')
    for tag in tags:
        film_title = tag.h3.string
        cinemas_count = len(
            tag.next_sibling.next_sibling.find_all(class_='b-td-item')
        )
        if min_showing_cinemas_count < cinemas_count:
            films_information[film_title] = cinemas_count
    return films_information


def fetch_movie_page(movie_title):
    url = 'https://www.kinopoisk.ru/index.php'
    params = {'kp_query': movie_title, 'first': 'yes', 'what': ''}
    response = fetch_page(url, params)
    return response


def parse_film_rating(film_html_raw):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(film_html_raw, 'html.parser')
    try:
        rating = soup.find(class_='rating_ball').string
        rating_count = soup.find(
            class_='ratingCount'
        ).string.replace(u'\xa0', '')
    except AttributeError:
        rating = 0
        rating_count = 0
    return float(rating), int(rating_count)


def output_movies_to_console(movies_info_list):
    first_ten_movies = 10
    movie_info_table = PrettyTable(
        ['Movie title', 'Rating', 'Rating count', 'Votes']
    )
    movie_info_table.align['Movie title'] = 'l'
    for movie in movies_info_list[:first_ten_movies]:
        print(movie)
        movie_info_table.add_row(movie)
    print(movie_info_table)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    afisha_page_url = 'https://www.afisha.ru/msk/schedule_cinema/'
    afisha_page_raw = fetch_page(afisha_page_url)
    print('Get a list of movies shown in the cinema from Afisha.ru...')
    showing_films = parse_afisha_list(afisha_page_raw.text)
    print('Get movies rating from Kinopoisk.ru...')
    movie_list_info = []
    for movie_name, votes in tqdm(
            showing_films.items(), desc='Collecting data:'
    ):
        movie_page = fetch_movie_page(movie_name)
        movie_rating, movie_rating_count = parse_film_rating(movie_page.text)
        movie_info = [movie_name, movie_rating, movie_rating_count, votes]
        movie_list_info.append(movie_info)
    sorted_movie_list = (sorted(
        movie_list_info, key=lambda movie: movie[1], reverse=True
    ))
    output_movies_to_console(sorted_movie_list)
```

вылетает ошибка

```
File "C:/devman/13_cinemas/cinemas.py", line 81, in <module>
    output_movies_to_console(list)
  File "C:/devman/13_cinemas/cinemas.py", line 61, in output_movies_to_console
    print(info_table)

  куча повторяющихся строк...

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\copy.py", line 215, in _deepcopy_list
    append(deepcopy(a, memo))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\copy.py", line 274, in _reconstruct
    y = func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\copyreg.py", line 88, in __newobj__
    return cls.__new__(cls, *args)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

берем из списка данные и пихает их в строку для prettytable такова вида ['Лед', 6171, 165]
если добавить print(movie) выведет ['Лед', 6171, 165]
при выводи таблицы выдает ошибку,
если строку добавлять ручками а не из списка, так info_table.add_row(['Лед', 6171, 165]) тогда prettytable отрабатывает как надо типы у обоих _list, в чем разница ?

Comment: от себя добавлю, что `list` не используйте для названия переменных, функций и т.п. Потому что это встроенная функция в языке: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Comment: А сколько элементов в `list`?

Comment: я поправил чтоб было понятней там не list там нормальное название не используется встроенных имен

Comment: по поводу количества не принципиально 1-15 не выводит, вручную info_table.add_row(['Лед', 6171, 165]) отрабатывает вывожу print(movie) выводит абсолютно туже строку ['Лед', 6171, 165], мало того я ее копирую и вставляю в => info_table.add_row(['Лед', 6171, 165])

Comment: @MadInc, приведите пример данных, с помощью которого можно воспроизвести ошибку

Comment: [['Три билборда на границе Эббинга, Миссури', 8.307, 45457, 83], ['Движение вверх', 8.271, 58356, 103], ['Приключения Паддингтона-2', 8.27, 8093, 92], ['Недруги', 7.489, 1031, 70], ['Призрачная нить', 7.426, 2787, 55], ['Лед', 7.15, 6203, 165], ['Сердцеед', 7.016, 23435, 100], ['Колесо чудес', 6.849, 2482, 92], ['Охота на воров', 6.725, 1924, 93], ['Бегущий в лабиринте: Лекарство от смерти', 6.301, 10473, 57], ['Селфи', 6.089, 5665, 120]] @MaxU

Comment: @MadInc, у меня все замечательно отрабатывает...

Comment: @MaxU если есть куда могу отправить весть листинг, есть подозрения на криво вставшие модули, надо попробовать в virtualnv запустить

Comment: можно выложить на любой свободный файлообменник...

Comment: @MaxU сюда выложил

Comment: @MadInc, хммм... похоже на баг в PrettyTable...

Comment: @MaxU Да вот какой то зашквар разработчика ))), проверил может тип не такой попадает нет типы одинаковые, список копировал которую получает переменная movie, я просто в ступоре ))) вроде самый элементарный код, а что не нравиться не понимаю )

Comment: @MaxU судя по логам первые четыре ошибки в файле prettytable.py, а потом куда то циклически проваливается в copy.py <= что это ? хз )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте воспользоваться модулем [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) - по-моему он более "продвинутый":

```
In [28]: from tabulate import tabulate

In [29]: headers = ['Movie title', 'Rating', 'Rating count', 'Votes']

In [33]: tab = tabulate(sorted_movie_list[:10], headers=headers, tablefmt='grid')

In [34]: print(tab)
+------------------------------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Movie title                              |   Rating |   Rating count |   Votes |
+==========================================+==========+================+=========+
| Три билборда на границе Эббинга, Миссури |    8.308 |          45572 |      83 |
+------------------------------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Лед                                      |    7.152 |           6250 |     165 |
+------------------------------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Пятьдесят оттенков свободы               |    5.541 |           9123 |     147 |
+------------------------------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Призрачная нить                          |    0     |              0 |      55 |
+------------------------------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Женщины против мужчин: Крымские каникулы |    0     |              0 |     139 |
+------------------------------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Движение вверх                           |    0     |              0 |     102 |
+------------------------------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Охота на воров                           |    0     |              0 |      93 |
+------------------------------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Недруги                                  |    0     |              0 |      70 |
+------------------------------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Приключения Паддингтона-2                |    0     |              0 |      92 |
+------------------------------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Плюшевый монстр                          |    0     |              0 |      59 |
+------------------------------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
```

Comment: хорошо попробую его спасибо большое за наводку

Comment: @MadInc, пожалуйста :)